# Flipclock Plugin isn´t working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, flipclock

I am using this clock in my homepage.

It isn´t working in IE.

What is the problem with IE and how I can solve it?

**[Working CodePen](https://codepen.io/goker/pen/jEALH)**

```js
/*
 * flipclock
 * Version: 1.0.1 
 * Authors: @gokercebeci
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 * Demo: http://
 */

(function($) {

    var pluginName = 'flipclock';

    var methods = {
        pad: function(n) {
            return (n < 10) ? '0' + n : n;
        },
        time: function(date) {
            if (date) {
                var e = new Date(date);
                var b = new Date();
                var d = new Date(e.getTime() - b.getTime());
            } else
                var d = new Date();
            var t = methods.pad(date ? d.getFullYear() - 70 : d.getFullYear())
                    + '' + methods.pad(date ? d.getMonth() : d.getMonth() + 1)
                    + '' + methods.pad(date ? d.getDate() - 1 : d.getDate())
                    + '' + methods.pad(d.getHours())
                    + '' + methods.pad(d.getMinutes())
                    + '' + methods.pad(d.getSeconds());
            return {
                'Y': {'d2': t.charAt(2), 'd1': t.charAt(3)},
                'M': {'d2': t.charAt(4), 'd1': t.charAt(5)},
                'D': {'d2': t.charAt(6), 'd1': t.charAt(7)},
                'h': {'d2': t.charAt(8), 'd1': t.charAt(9)},
                'm': {'d2': t.charAt(10), 'd1': t.charAt(11)},
                's': {'d2': t.charAt(12), 'd1': t.charAt(13)}
            };
        },
        play: function(c) {
            $('body').removeClass('play');
            var a = $('ul' + c + ' section.active');
            if (a.html() == undefined) {
                a = $('ul' + c + ' section').eq(0);
                a.addClass('ready')
                        .removeClass('active')
                        .next('section')
                        .addClass('active')
                        .closest('body')
                        .addClass('play');

            }
            else if (a.is(':last-child')) {
                $('ul' + c + ' section').removeClass('ready');
                a.addClass('ready').removeClass('active');
                a = $('ul' + c + ' section').eq(0);
                a.addClass('active')
                        .closest('body')
                        .addClass('play');
            }
            else {
                $('ul' + c + ' section').removeClass('ready');
                a.addClass('ready')
                        .removeClass('active')
                        .next('section')
                        .addClass('active')
                        .closest('body')
                        .addClass('play');
            }
        },
        // d1 is first digit and d2 is second digit
        ul: function(c, d2, d1) {
            return '<ul class="flip ' + c + '">' + this.li('d2', d2) + this.li('d1', d1) + '</ul>';
        },
        li: function(c, n) {
            //
            return '<li class="' + c + '"><section class="ready"><div class="up">'
                    + '<div class="shadow"></div>'
                    + '<div class="inn"></div></div>'
                    + '<div class="down">'
                    + '<div class="shadow"></div>'
                    + '<div class="inn"></div></div>'
                    + '</section><section class="active"><div class="up">'
                    + '<div class="shadow"></div>'
                    + '<div class="inn">' + n + '</div></div>'
                    + '<div class="down">'
                    + '<div class="shadow"></div>'
                    + '<div class="inn">' + n + '</div></div>'
                    + '</section></li>';
        }
    };
    // var defaults = {};
    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = options;
        // this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        // this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }
    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            var t, full = false;

            if (!this.options || this.options == 'clock') {

                t = methods.time();

            } else if (this.options == 'date') {

                t = methods.time();
                full = true;

            } else {

                t = methods.time(this.options);
                full = true;

            }

            $(this.element)
                    .addClass('flipclock')
                    .html(
                    (full ?
                            methods.ul('year', t.Y.d2, t.Y.d1)
                            + methods.ul('month', t.M.d2, t.M.d1)
                            + methods.ul('day', t.D.d2, t.D.d1)
                            : '')
                    + methods.ul('hour', t.h.d2, t.h.d1)
                    + methods.ul('minute', t.m.d2, t.m.d1)
                    + methods.ul('second', t.s.d2, t.s.d1)
                    + '<audio id="flipclick">'
                    + '<source src="https://github.com/gokercebeci/flipclock/blob/master/js/plugins/flipclock/click.mp3?raw=true" type="audio/mpeg"/>'
                    + '</audio>');

            setInterval($.proxy(this.refresh, this), 1000);

        },
        refresh: function() {
            var el = $(this.element);
            var t;
            if (this.options
                    && this.options != 'clock'
                    && this.options != 'date') {

                t = methods.time(this.options);

            } else
                t = methods.time()

            // second sound
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById('flipclick').play()
            }, 500);

            // second first digit
            el.find(".second .d1 .ready .inn").html(t.s.d1);
            methods.play('.second .d1');
            // second second digit
            if ((t.s.d1 === '0')) {
                el.find(".second .d2 .ready .inn").html(t.s.d2);
                methods.play('.second .d2');
                // minute first digit
                if ((t.s.d2 === '0')) {
                    el.find(".minute .d1 .ready .inn").html(t.m.d1);
                    methods.play('.minute .d1');
                    // minute second digit
                    if ((t.m.d1 === '0')) {
                        el.find(".minute .d2 .ready .inn").html(t.m.d2);
                        methods.play('.minute .d2');
                        // hour first digit
                        if ((t.m.d2 === '0')) {
                            el.find(".hour .d1 .ready .inn").html(t.h.d1);
                            methods.play('.hour .d1');
                            // hour second digit
                            if ((t.h.d1 === '0')) {
                                el.find(".hour .d2 .ready .inn").html(t.h.d2);
                                methods.play('.hour .d2');
                                // day first digit
                                if ((t.h.d2 === '0')) {
                                    el.find(".day .d1 .ready .inn").html(t.D.d1);
                                    methods.play('.day .d1');
                                    // day second digit
                                    if ((t.D.d1 === '0')) {
                                        el.find(".day .d2 .ready .inn").html(t.D.d2);
                                        methods.play('.day .d2');
                                        // month first digit
                                        if ((t.D.d2 === '0')) {
                                            el.find(".month .d1 .ready .inn").html(t.M.d1);
                                            methods.play('.month .d1');
                                            // month second digit
                                            if ((t.M.d1 === '0')) {
                                                el.find(".month .d2 .ready .inn").html(t.M.d2);
                                                methods.play('.month .d2');
                                                // year first digit
                                                if ((t.M.d2 === '0')) {
                                                    el.find(".year .d1 .ready .inn").html(t.Y.d1);
                                                    methods.play('.year .d1');
                                                    // year second digit
                                                    if ((t.Y.d1 === '0')) {
                                                        el.find(".year .d2 .ready .inn").html(t.Y.d2);
                                                        methods.play('.year .d2');
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        },
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (!$(this).data('plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $(this).data('plugin_' + pluginName,
                        new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });
    };

})(typeof jQuery !== 'undefined' ? jQuery : Zepto);


// RUN
$('#container').flipclock();
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font: 11px/normal sans-serif;
    background-image: url('https://github.com/gokercebeci/flipclock/raw/master/css/background.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
#mask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://github.com/gokercebeci/flipclock/raw/master/css/mask.png');
    z-index: 2;
}
h1 { 
  margin: 0 10px; 
  font-size: 70px; 
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
}
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
#page {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}
#container {
    opacity: .9;
}
#usage li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #222;
    background: #fff;
}
#usage code {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background: #000;
}

/*
 * flipclock
 * Version: 1.0.0 
 * Authors: @gokercebeci
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 * Demo: http://
*/

/*==============================================================================
    FLIP CLOCK
==============================================================================*/
.flipclock {
}
.flipclock hr {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 65px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    border: 0;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;
}
ul.flip {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 180px;
    height: 130px;
    font-size: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 127px;
}

ul.flip li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 49%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-perspective: 200px;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.flip li.d1 {
    float: right;
}

ul.flip li section {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

ul.flip li section:first-child {
    z-index: 2;
}

ul.flip li div {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 49%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul.flip li div .shadow {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

ul.flip li div.up {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    top: 0;
}

ul.flip li div.down {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    bottom: 0;
}

ul.flip li div div.inn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200%;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

ul.flip li div.up div.inn {
    top: 0;

}

ul.flip li div.down div.inn {
    bottom: 0;
}

/*--------------------------------------
 PLAY
--------------------------------------*/

body.play ul section.ready {
    z-index: 3;
}

body.play ul section.active {
    -webkit-animation: index .5s .5s linear both;
    z-index: 2;
}

@-webkit-keyframes index {
    0% {
        z-index: 2;
    }
    5% {
        z-index: 4;
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 4;
    }
}

body.play ul section.active .down {
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-animation: flipdown .5s .5s linear both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flipdown {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    }  
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(5deg);
    } 
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(15deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
}

body.play ul section.ready .up {
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-animation: flipup .5s linear both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flipup {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }  
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
}

/*--------------------------------------
 SHADOW
--------------------------------------*/

body.play ul section.ready .up .shadow {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)));
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    -webkit-animation: show .5s linear both;
}

body.play ul section.active .up .shadow {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)));
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    -webkit-animation: hide .5s .3s linear both;
}

/*DOWN*/

body.play ul section.ready .down .shadow {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)));
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    -webkit-animation: show .5s linear both;
}

body.play ul section.active .down .shadow {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)));
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 100%);
    -webkit-animation: hide .5s .3s linear both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes show {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    90% {
        opacity: .10;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hide {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }  
    80% {
        opacity: .20;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.0/zepto.min.js"></script>
<div id="mask">
    <div id="page">
        <h1>flipclock</h1>

        <div id="container"></div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <h2>USAGE</h2>
        <ul id="usage">
            <li class="selected">
                clock
                <code>$('#container').flipclock();</code>
            </li>
            <li>
                fulldate
                <code>$('#container').flipclock('date');</code>
            </li>
            <li>
                countdown
                <code>$('#container').flipclock('2013 01 17 12:00:00');</code>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: every version..
it should work in 11, 10 if possible 9/8

Comment: it works for me in IE 11

Comment: That code have several properties which has the `-webkit-` prefix, most of them without a global property, fix that and it will work in those who support those properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your tipps and support!

I solved the problem. Older IE-Versions couldn´t read the DATE format..

i had:

```
flipclock('2016 01 16 11:00:00');
```

but for IE it should be:

```
flipclock('2017-01-16T11:00:00.000Z');
```